# Python: httplib request() not working

Tags: python, httplib

I'm having issues using httplib's request() method.  It's a really odd problem.  My code looks like this:

```
query = "/search.json?q=&geocode=" + slat + "," + slong + "," + mline[2] + "km&rpp=" + mline[3]
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("search.twitter.com")
conn.request("GET", query) #request here
r1 = conn.getresponse()
preresult = r1.read()

print preresult
```

So the problem is, nothing prints out.  `query` is made up of a ton of other strings concatenated.  What's really strange is if I set `query` equal to the actual value of the string (that is, actually set it equal to say, `"/search.json?q=&geocode=27.5916,086.5640,100km&rpp=2"` as opposed to tons of other strings concatenated), then it prints out as it should.  I got that value of `query` by doing `print query` after concatenation in the code above.  So to make things clear, the following works fine (using the value of `print query` from above):

```
query = "/search.json?q=&geocode=27.5916,086.5640,100km&rpp=2"
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("search.twitter.com")
conn.request("GET", query) #request here
r1 = conn.getresponse()
preresult = r1.read()

print preresult
```

The value of `query` should be identical in both implementations.  I checked `query`'s type in the 1st implementation to make sure it's a string.  But they give different results.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What does `print r1.status, r1.length` say with your 'faulty' query?

Comment: `400` and `0`, respectively

Comment: When I do it with the 2nd implementation, I get `200` and `1756`, respectively

Comment: I get `200` and `0` for both implementations, although both implementations I had to guess on some missing code because neither is a complete example.  Post complete, short, working examples exhibiting reproducible behavior.

Comment: I get `200` and a varying size (which is to be expected) for both (I used the values from the second as the values of the variables used in the first). `400` means `Bad Request`, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out mline[3] had some invisible character at the end.  It wasn't a newline or an whitespace....but I just converted it to an int first, then converted it back to a string and the extra character disappeared and my problem went away.  Thanks for all your help.